# Application form email template

Tags: html, email, templates, outlook

I programmed a HTML application form which I insert into my MySQL database. 
After that i send the application form data as a HTML E-Mail to the applicant.

Does anyone know (responsive) HTML E-Mail templates which i can use for this?
I can only find templates for newsletters etc. I want to send the application
data in a "list" design

Answer (score 0):

Forms in an HTML email have been a risky venture for a long time and still continue today.  It places a security risk that some email clients flat out block interactivity with it (e.g. Outlook) and most others have some sort of warning or limited capability filter on them. ([Campaign Monitor](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/2435/how-forms-perform-in-html-emai/))

There is also speculation (but no real solid facts) that HTML forms can reduce deliverability to some ISPs.

It is recommended to send the recipient to a landing page to fill in a form there via their web browser where the security risk is greatly reduced and so are the restrictions and weird behavior that email servers can present.

If you were aware of all this and sending to only an audience that can receive and submit these no problem, I would recommend looking at this code style for your design - [Hybrid Code](http://labs.actionrocket.co/the-hybrid-coding-approach-2)